# how to do a proximity search with entity framework (spatial)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, entity-framework-4

I know that the entity framework does not currently support geo types but there has to be a way to do a proximity search with the entity framework. 
please if anyone has any ideas please shoot them my way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a stored procedure that accepts a lat and long value, map that stored procedure in your Entity Framework model and then filter on the results of the stored procedure.

Comment: Sorry for the delay on checking back on this but I did this and it seems to work pretty darn good. Unfortunately I am still so new to MVC and the whole Entity framework and had so many other issues with design I have decided to put that version of my project on hold till I have a good working version of it in webforms instead.

Answer (score 0):

you need a reference location (lat/long). then in each entity your also need a lat/long. You can then use a havesine distance calculation and order by the distance. This can all be done using linq quite easily.